# Undefined is not a Function-Sails Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, sails.js

Hi I am trying to write a logic in Sails using Mongoose to find and update the parameters in the Mongoose Database using Serial No which is in String format.The parameters which I am passing are in the the Body of the DHC App(Used for POSTING Data to the API). While Posting the Data, I am Getting the Following error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.module.exports.createORupdateStatus (/Users/febinp/Downloads/Shubham_application/taqua-parser/api/controllers/Status-packetController.js:66:26)
at bound (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
at nextRoute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)
at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:187:7
at alwaysAllow (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/policies/index.js:207:11)
at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
at nextRoute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)
at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:187:7
at clearHeaders (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/cors/index.js:209:3)
at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5) [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
```

Using Node Inspector I Found that the Code is failing for my FindOneAndUpdate which is as follows

```
var msg_parts=params.msg_parts;
          /*msg_parts.SerialNo=params.SerialNo;*/   // Adding the Serial no into the message parts for storing in the mongo Database

     var statuspacket=db.StatusPacket(msg_parts);

        //For saving into the Database
        statuspacket.findOneAndUpdate({"SerialNo":SerialNo1},msg_parts,function(err,data){
                if (err) {
                        res.json({
                                success: false,
                                exception: err
                        });
                            return;
                }else{                  
                            statuspacket.save(function(err,data){
                                if(err){ 
                                            res.json({
                                                success: false,
                                                exception: err
                                            });
                                          return;
                                        }else{
                                                res.json({
                                                    success: true,
                                                    data:data
                                            });
                                        return;  
                                      }
                        });  
                }
        });
```

MY Schema for the Database is as follows

```
 var schema=new mongoose.Schema({
    // Serial No of the device.We require an Index on this column
    SerialNo:{
         type: String,
         required:true,
         index:true
    },
   // battery level will take values from 0 to 6(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
   batteryLevel:{
        type:Number,
        min:0,   
        max:6
    },
    //Signal Level will take values from 0 to 4 (0,1,2,3,4)
    signalLevel:{
            type:Number,
            min:0,   
            max:4,
     },
    //Charging status=false represents Charging OFF And true represents charging on
    chargingStatus:{
            type:Boolean,   
            default:false
   },
    // 7 states of the alarm 
    alarmInfo:{
          type:Number
  },
    // false represents GPS OFF And true represents GPS on  
    gpsStatus:{
            type:Boolean
  },
    //Default time when the new packet arrived    
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
  });
```

Can Somebody Help Me with the Error as I am Unable to Understand where I am going Wrong in FindOneAndUpdate?